# How can I get another Ender Dragon Egg if I lose one?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend fell off the map and lost his Ender Dragon Egg. Is it possible to get another one without using cheats?

Answer (score 1):

Only the first ender dragon killed will spawn the egg, so the only ways to get it again are either to reset the end or using cheats.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You'll only receive it when you first killed the Ender Dragon. You have to use cheats.

Command:

```
/give @a dragon_egg
```

Comment: ' "Is it possible to get another one with using cheats?" no, only using cheats '  ...what?

Comment: Yes, there is. If theres 2 friends, the one that took the last swipe and killed the dragon, that person can't kill the dragon and get the egg again.  But the other person can kill the dragon again and get the egg. If there's only 1 player... There's nothing that you can do...Sorry if that's the case

Comment: Notice: The person that took the last swipe and killed the dragon can't get involved in the next dragon fight.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a second dragon egg by respawning the dragon using end crystals and then when I killed it again, I got another egg.